# What is the use of sigsetjmp() return value?

Tags: c, operating-system

As part of an exercise, I have to implement a library that support the use of user level threads.

I should use the system calls `sigsetjmp` and `siglongjmp`.

Now I am struggling to understand the use of `sigsetjmp` return value.

If I understood right, the return value will be be the second input for the last `siglongjmp` (In case it is not the first `sigsetjmp`).

When we want to switch threads, we call `sigsetjmp` to keep the registers values in the CPU in some place in the memory.

Right after we will call `siglongjmp` In order to load some values inside the CPU registers, so our next thread can keep running from the exact spot it halted. When calling `siglongjmp` we also provide and integer for the next `sigsetjmp` **return** value.

If I was right so far, I don't understand what would be the use of knowing something about the last thread, which is not running anymore, and we already kept its CPU values in the memory (because the `sigsetjmp` returned).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return value from `sigsetjmp()` tells you whether it is being called for the first time (return value 0), or whether it is returning as the result of a `siglongjmp()` (return value non-zero).   The behaviour of `sigjmp()` and `longjmp()` is the same.  The first time call sets the `sigjmp_buf` or `jmp_buf` argument to record the state of the computation so that `siglongjmp()` or `setjmp()` can use it to jump back.

Note that you should be careful about how you use `sigsetjmp()` and `setjmp()`; the contexts in which they can be used are every restricted.
C11 [§7.13.1.1 The `setjmp` macro](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.13.1.1) says:

> ¶4 An invocation of the setjmp macro shall appear only in one of the following contexts:
>
> - the entire controlling expression of a selection or iteration statement;
> - one operand of a relational or equality operator with the other operand an integer constant expression, with the resulting expression being the entire controlling expression of a selection or iteration statement;
> - the operand of a unary `!` operator with the resulting expression being the entire controlling expression of a selection or iteration statement; or
> - the entire expression of an expression statement (possibly cast to void).
>
> ¶5 If the invocation appears in any other context, the behavior is undefined.

Note, in particular, that none of the contexts where it may be used is 'on the RHS of an assignment statement'.  Having pointed that out, I've never seen an assignment fail, but technically, it is invoking undefined behaviour to assign the result.

Also note that the C standard says explicitly that `setjmp()` is a macro.

The C standard does not define `sigsetjmp()` or `siglongjmp()` — they are POSIX extensions to the C standard.  However, the POSIX rules are basically the same:

- [`setjmp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setjmp.html)
- [`longjmp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/longjmp.html)
- [`sigsetjmp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigsetjmp.html)
- [`siglongjimp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/siglongjimp.html)

One reason for this is that the construction of a good, working `setjmp()`/`longjmp()` pair is an extremely delicate piece of code.
If you can find a copy, it would be worth reading
P J Plauger [The Standard C Library](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/0131315099) (1992) on the topic.  Even though it is old, there is a lot of wisdom in its discussions.

Answer (score 2):

The return value of `sigsetjmp` is the value given to the [eventual] `siglongjmp` 2nd argument.

By convention, this is non-zero (if `siglongjmp` is passed 0, it will use 1).

The value returned by `sigsetjmp` is how the caller distinguishes "normal" operation vs. the event/signal occurred.

The first time the return is 0. The caller will now do "normal" operations.

When the `siglongjmp` is called, the stack is reset to the point of the `sigsetjmp` call. But, the return value will be non-zero, telling the caller that the event triggered and the caller should do "abort" processing.

The non-zero value in question [again] comes from the 2nd argument to `siglongjmp`. It can be *any* non-zero value. Thus, we can use it as an "abort" type code. (e.g.) It could be the signal number that occurred if we wish.

Or, any value: (e.g.) `enum { ABORT_NOFILE = 100, ABORT_NOMEM, ABORT_BECAUSE_ITS_TUESDAY };` that the two invokers/callers agree on.

Anyway, here's some code to illustrate:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <setjmp.h>

sigjmp_buf jmpbuf;
int termval = 23;

void
handler(int sig)
{

    siglongjmp(jmpbuf,termval);
}

int
main(void)
{
#if 0
    int retval;
#else
    volatile static int retval;
#endif

    signal(SIGALRM,handler);

    retval = sigsetjmp(jmpbuf,1);

    if (! retval) {
        alarm(5);

        printf("running normally ...\n");

        // do something useful ...
        while (1);
    }
    else {
        printf("signal occurred -- retval=%d\n",retval);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that according to the rules of POSIX and the C standard, you can't assign the result of `sigsetjmp()` or `setjmp()`.  That said, I've not seen an assignment go wrong, but it is, strictly, undefined behaviour.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I've never seen that before. But, you _can_ assign it as I did originally, because `retval` _must_ be set from the `sigsetjmp` return value and the compiler can't elide any code based on the value [because it only knows the value at runtime]. You may not be able to rely upon other automatic (i.e. register based) values, but the return can be assigned to a variable. If the spec says otherwise, it _is_ wrong because of what goes into the `sigjmp_buf` struct and the value in question is returned (e.g. in `%eax` on x86).